# General solution for a special case of the Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, klein-gordon-equation

I am trying to find the general solution for the following special case of the Klein-Gordon equation:

$$ {\partial^2f(x,y)\over{\partial x^2}} -c^2{\partial^2f(x,y)\over{\partial y^2}}+g(x)f(x,y)=0\tag1$$

where $x$ and $y$ are the general coordinates, $c$ is a constant, $g(x)$ is a **known** function of only $x$ and $f(x,y)$ is the unknown function which represents the general solution of equation $(1)$.

[Here](https://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/lpde/lpde203.pdf), I found some particular solutions to equation $(1)$ for the case where $g(x)$ is not a function of $x$, but a constant. Also, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation) can be found a general solution to the Klein-Gordon equation, but also for the case where $g(x) = const$.

Since I did not find in literature the general solution to equation $(1)$, I tryed deriving it myself. However, I did not cucceed. So my questions are:

- Does a general solution to equation $(1)$ even exist? If it does, what is it?

I need to answer these questions so I can design the funtion $g(x)$ for my project. Thank you for your time.

Comment: When I wrote the answer I assumed that $x$ is a time variable and $y$ a space variable with $y\in\mathbb R$. If your $y$ is only in an interval and the solution has to satisfy boundary conditions we need to take this into account. For a finite interval only discrete $\lambda$ will then be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's follow Helmholtz' classic method which  leads from the wave equation to the [Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation):

Separating variables $f(x,y)=u(x)v(y)$ we get
\begin{align}
u''v-c^2uv''+guv=0\,,
\end{align}
that is,
\begin{align}
\frac{u''}{u}+g=c^2\frac{v''}{v}\,.
\end{align}
The left hand side depends only on $x$ and the right hand side only on $y$. Therefore there must be a constant $\lambda$ such that
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\frac{u''}{u}+g=\lambda\,,\quad c^2\frac{v''}{v}=\lambda.
\end{align}
Can you solve these two linear ODEs ?

The general solution for your linear Klein-Gordon equation will be a superposition of all solutions of (1), i.e., an integral over $\lambda$.

Comment: +1 What is precisely  Helmholtz' classic method ?

Comment: It is the separation of variables that leads from the wave equation to the [Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation). I think that OP's solutions he found for the case of constant $g$ are exactly the solutions of Helmholtz' equation.

Comment: thank you so  much  Kurt for your explanation

Comment: I made a mistake by not specifying the initial and boundary conditions in my question. $x$ belongs to an interval of $[0, x_{max}]$ and $y$ belongs to an interval of $[0, y_{max}]$.
The conditions that need to met are: $f(x,0)={\partial{f(x,y)}\over\partial{x}}|_{y=0}=0$, $f(0,y)=F(y) $ and  ${\partial{f(x,y)}\over\partial{y}}|_{x=0}={dF(y)\over{dy}}$. Note that $F(y)$ and ${dF(y)\over{dy}}$ are known. I am still trying to solve your equation $(1)$ by including these conditions. Also,  $c^2$ is missing in your equation $(1)$ and the $g$ in your equation $(1)$ should be positive, not negative.